# Finding displacement as a function of time given a Force F(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If I have a force $F = 4 - 2x$ and want to find the displacement as a function of time i.e. $x(t)$ I'm confused why the answer wouldn't just be $4 - 2x$ integrated twice. Also for this question $m = 1$ so I don't need to worry about it for now.

If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. I've tried searching for an answer but I don't think I'm searching correctly and I'm really disappointed I can't answer this

Answer (score 1):

The displacement is just the acceleration integrated twice, but it is integrated with respect to time.  To get the velocity you would integrate once, so you have $v=v_0+\int_o^\tau x(\tau) d\tau$.  We don't (yet) know what $x(\tau)$ is so we cannot do the integral.  The differential equation approach solves this problem.  If we write $F=x''$ because you have $m=1$ you get $x''=4-2x$.  You still need starting conditions before you get a complete solution.

Comment: If I wanted a general solution however would I just integrate $x''$ twice in order to get $2t^2 - \frac{t^3}{3} + c_1 t + c_2$ But I don't really understand the variables here since I'm not supposed to use x in my answer but when I differentiate my answer twice it should give me $4-2x$ sorry I'm just really confused

Comment: No, you are missing the difference between integrating $x$ and $t$.  You would be correct if the force were $4-2t$ but that is not what you have.

Comment: So how would I approach it? I saw somewhere about using the chain rule method to give $\frac{1}{2} v^2 = \int F(x) dx$ and I understand how to get to this point but once I've integrated $4-2x$ wrt $x$ I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: The usual approach is to write the equation as $x''+2x=4$, find one (particular) solution to the whole equation and the general solution to the equation with the right side $0$.  Here the general solution is $x=a \cos (\sqrt 2 t) + b\sin (\sqrt 2 t)$ and a particular solution is $x=2$ independent of $t$ so $x''=0$.  Now use $a$  and $b$ to match the starting conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I appreciate your help a lot!!!